# How to predicate with relationships in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a database with next tables:

```
Car
Sector
```

where in `Car` I have a relation One-to-Many, `carHasSectors` and in `Sector` I have `sectorInCar`.

Now I want to write a predicate which will search in `Sector` table but through `Car` table. For that I do:

```
let p3 = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.carHasSectors.sectorName CONTAINS[c] %@ ", searchText)
```

where `SELF` is `Car`

but it cannot find anything in result.
What I do wrong? Cannot I go to `Sector` with dot notation in Core Data?

Comment: Note that `carHasSectors.sectorName` is a collection of sector names, so CoreData interprets the `CONTAINS` as "does this collection contain the searchtext" or, put another way, "is there an element of this collection which is **equal to** the searchText".  It will only match if the sectorName is equal to the searchText.  If that's your problem, you need to build a more complex predicate which evaluates each sector separately, for which I recommend using SUBQUERY: "SUBQUERY(carHasSectors, $S, $S.sectorName CONTAINS[c] %@).@count >0".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the cars which have a sector with a particular name. I think you should perform your request on the Sector table with something like `NSPredicate(format: "sectorName CONTAINS[c] %@ ", searchText)` and then map the list of sectors you will get into a list of cars.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Get the objects without fetch from the relationship (`car` is the current `Car`)

   ```
   let result = (car.carHasSectors.allObjects as! [Sector])
                                  .filter{$0.sectorName.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
   ```
2. Fetch **`Sector`** with predicate

   ```
   NSPredicate(format: "sectorInCar.name == %@ AND sectorName CONTAINS[c] %@ ", carName, searchText)
   ```